# Client and Server in One Application

Tags: javascript, mobile, bluetooth, client

Erm pardon me if this is a stupid question.

Is it possible for a client application to also include server functionality and vice versa?

For example - I want to write a bluetooth application which is a server application, communicates with the bluetooth client. And the same application can include the client functionality and have as a bluetooth client?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few things confused... I don't see how you can connect through javascript to bluetooth! For this type of application you shouldn't be thinking in terms of javascript or web application.

You can do what you want in some programming language of choice for which you can find libraries to allow you to connect via bluetooth. How you design your software is up to you. You can make your software act both as a bluetooth sender and receiver so in this sense each will be both a client and a server.

Comment: I will be using palm webos to develop the application using Bluetooth SPP using the Enyo framework. https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/bluetooth.html. Your answer was very useful! thank you!